# Adb install can't find google to install

Tags: android

I have created an emulator(level14) and i want to install google play services on it.
I downloaded this files on sdk\platform-tools:
Google Maps.apk
google-play-services-5.0.89.apk
when i used the cmd and enter the command line:

```
C:\Users\SLIM\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools>adb install Google Maps.apk
```

I get this error'message:can't find Google to install.
Same thing for google play services.

Comment: Is `Google Maps.apk` the apk filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spaces in your fielname, so you have to surround it with `"`

Try running

```
C:\Users\SLIM\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools>adb install "Google Maps.apk"
```